# How to return to the main thread from a callback called on another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, eventlet

I'd like to execute my code from a background callback into the main thread. For some reasons I didn't found simple examples to perform that.

I found example with Queue and pooling, this is clearly not what I want. I just want to join the main thread in order to execute my function.

Here is some simple code:

```
def my_callback:
    # this callback is called from a third party and I don't have control on it. 
    # But because of this, the function must_be_executed_on_main_thread is
    # executed on the background.
    must_be_executed_on_main_thread()

def must_be_executed_on_main_thread:
    # must be executed on the main thread.
```

** Edit **

Here is my problem:
main file:

```
if __main__ == '__main__'
    sio = socketio.Server()
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)

    # now the thread is blocking into the server pool
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen('', 7000)), app)
```

from another file, I've got a decorator who deal with the socket event:

```
@sio.on('test')
def test(sid, data):
    print threading.currentThread()
    sio.emit('event triggered')
```

And here is the problem: I have some events triggered by an hardware button, which trigger a callback who call sio "test" event. But because the events are not triggered into the same thread, this cause me some trouble:

```
# async call !
def event_cb(num):
    sio.emit('test')

GPIO.add_event_detect(btNumber, GPIO.RISING, event_cb)
```

the test method decorator is called:
but when the emit is done not on the main thread, this stop working.

as long as the socket call are done from the **Mainthread**, it is ok. 
but when one call is done on **DummyThread**, this not working anymore.

I test on a client device with socket.io implementation. As long as the "emit" are done on the mainthread, it works, but when I perform on another thread (like with a button who trigger the callback, it stop working)

That's why I'd love to perform

Comment: "stop working" is not a definitive description of problem.

If you don't want `wsgi.server` to block main thread, do `eventlet.spawn(eventlet.wsgi.server, listen(...), app)`. Don't forget to call `eventlet.sleep(0)` periodically to ensure Eventlet main loop has a chance to process network events.

Also, you may try `monkey_patch(threading=True)`, that way there will always be one OS thread.

Also be aware of `button bounce` (google it). Proper way to work with buttons is either Linux gpio-keys or manual debouncing via sampling.

Comment: Depending on the performance requirements doing the loop yourself (and not in C by some lib) may or may not be viable. It will most definitely work though. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can easily pass values between threads by using a `Queue` instance.

This simple demonstration script explains the concept. You can abort the script using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Queue
import random
import threading
import time

def main_thread():
    """Our main loop in the main thread.

    It receives the values via a Queue instance which it passes on to the
    other threads on thread start-up.
    """
    queue = Queue.Queue()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_in_other_thread,
                              args=(queue,))
    thread.daemon = True  # so you can quit the demo program easily :)
    thread.start()

    while True:
         val = queue.get()
         print "from main-thread", val

def run_in_other_thread(queue):
    """Our worker thread.

    It passes it's generated values on the the main-thread by just
    putting them into the `Queue` instance it got on start-up.
    """
    while True:
         queue.put(random.random())
         time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_thread()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I can't design my code this way: I must run an eventlet.wsgi.server() on the main thread. This one run a server blocking the main thread. And because there is no event loop, I'm kinda stuck.

Comment: @MrBonjour Ok. Please modify your question to include all relevant information then.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually a little lost. I'm trying to implement a derivative of your example. This is close but because of the eventlet, I'm trying to call my socket objet from the same thread. I will modify my question since I thought you can reinsere data throught a thread via his event loop. But that don't exist in this case.

Comment: There is event loop in Eventlet. It's running when any greenthread is going to sleep or wait for network IO or for another event. Queue is the most correct way to synchronise OS threads and should work for you. Code example in question does not mention how Queue wouldn't work.